# Wordpress display posts category in loop

Tags: posts

I am working on a WordPress theme and this is my code to display posts.

However I'm struggling to display all categories for a post. Most solutions don't work for me but do for others. That's also the reason why I post my full code on here because this code may not be the best one to use.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
    ?>
            <article id="post-5" class="slide taken" data-background-l="dark" data-background-p="dark" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                <header class="page-header caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="title" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h6 class="subtitle"><?php echo $cats[0]->name; ?></h6>
                        <div class="excerpt" itemprop="description"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
                        <a class="mitch-button to-load dark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-i="1" data-title="Lapka"><span>View Post<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  x="0" y="0" width="24" height="42" viewBox="0 0 24 42" enable-background="new 0 0 24 42" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="dark" points="23.3 20.1 23.3 20.1 23.3 20.1 20.1 23.3 20.1 23.3 3.1 40.3 0 37.1 17 20.1 0 3.1 3.1 0 20.1 17 20.1 17 "/></svg></span></a>
                    </div>
                </header> 
                <div class="media" data-bg-small="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1-1-1920x1071.jpg" data-bg-full="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1-1.jpg" data-bg-small-p="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1_vertical-855x1140.jpg" data-bg-large-p="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1_vertical-1110x1480.jpg" data-bg-full-p="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1_vertical.jpg">
                    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1-1-960x535.jpg" alt="Lapka" data-lazyload="innoway" itemprop="image" srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJH/AP///wAAAMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAABAAEAAAICVAEAOw==" />
                </div>
            </article>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
endif; ?>
```

Comment: There are many usefull answers on-site on how to use `get_the_category()` and related functions to display a list of post categories

Answer (score 1):

The below code check that post have category or not. If post have category then it will display list of category separate by comma. You can try this code. Hope this will help you.

```
if(has_category())
{
   echo $cats_list = get_the_category_list(', ');

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Is there any way to remove the link from the cats?